# What is the right tem for automated arm for door open / close

Tags: robotic-arm

I would like to make a wildlife feeder that would be something like this:

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/68746358372/

but I would want to have an arm / lever of some kind that would be able to open the top. I searched alibaba for "door arm" and some other terms but get a lot of junk like full size door openers that are not what I'm looking for. I don't know the right term for the arm apparatus that would be ideal for this.

Another design might be a 55 gallon lengthwise horizontal with arms to open 1/4 size doors.  What is the technical or common term for what I'm after?

This is sort of what I'd like to accomplish, but it looks like a piston of some kind:

https://tectonic-usa.com/

Comment: door strut ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a word for this: you're looking to attach some kind of actuator to a door, and there are many ways to go about that. Here's a few that might help in your searching:

- Linear Actuator: this allows you to apply motion (actuate) in a line (linear). This could be mounted to some door mechanism in place of a piston.
- Servo motor: with a lever arm this could be mounted to the door to provide an opening mechanism.
- Stepper motor: as above.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks!